# Python Web Request Error 403

Tags: python, http, http-status-code-403

I am having issues accessing a web page using python -- its throwing a HTTP Error 403. After browsing stack overflow I found many other users encountering the same error and remedying it by changing the header of the request. I tried this but still receive the error.

Here is my code:

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://www.mozilla.org")
req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8a3) Gecko/20040817')

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError, (err):
    print "URL error(%s)" % (err)
```

EDIT: Here is a larger chunk of my code, its the beginning of a web crawler. Also -- I have been using http://www.mozilla.org as my test url, though it does not seem to work for any other urls such as google and yahoo.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import urllib2
import urlparse
tocrawl = set([sys.argv[1]])
crawled = set([])

while 1:
    try:
        crawling = tocrawl.pop()
        print 'Crawling: ', crawling
    except KeyError:
        print 'No more to crawl!'
        raise StopIteration

    url = urlparse.urlparse(crawling)
    print 'Url parse returned ', url

    req = urllib2.Request(crawling)
    req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8a3) Gecko/20040817')
    print 'header: ', req.get_header('User-agent')

    try:
        print 'test'
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        print 'test2'
        print 'response: ', response
    except urllib2.URLError, (err):
        print "URL error(%s)" % (err)
        continue

    msg = response.read()
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to fetch http://www.mozilla.org?  Because your code works fine for me.  If not, its hard to say specifically without the URL you're trying to fetch.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results. Can you share any more code that might be causing a problem? Also is there an error message in the body of the response?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED. The problem was I wasn't setting up the necessary proxies. Thanks for the responses.

I added the following code snippet in order to fix.

```
proxy_info = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http' : "proxy:80"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_info)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```